# MongoDB not using even the simplest index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

Please look at the following example. It seems to me that the query should be covered by the index `{a: 1}`, however `explain()` gives me an `indexOnly: false`. What I am doing wrong?

```
> db.foo.save({a: 1, b: 2});
> db.foo.save({a: 2, b: 3});
> db.foo.ensureIndex({a: 1});
> db.foo.find({a: 1}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1",
    "nscanned" : 6,
    "nscannedObjects" : 6,
    "n" : 6,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "a" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's using the index as shown by the `cursor` being a `BtreeCursor`. There are six docs apparently -- is there something about the others by any chance that's causing this behavior?

Comment: I think your interpretation of 'indexOnly' is off, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexes-covered-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index only denotes a covered query ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexes-covered-queries ) whereby the query and its sort and data can all be found within a single index.

The problem with your query:

```
db.foo.find({a: 1}).explain();
```

Is that it must retrieve the full document which means it cannot find all data within the index. Instead you can use:

```
db.foo.find({a: 1}, {_id:0,a:1}).explain();
```

Which will mean you only project the `a` field which makes the entire query fit into the index, and so `indexOnly` being true.